# Removing Title Tag from Thumbnails

Tags: images, post-thumbnails, thumbnails

I'm currently adding thumbnails to my page with: `<?php the_post_thumbnail( 'category-thumb' ); ?>` and this in the fuctions.php:

```
if ( function_exists( 'add_image_size' ) ) {
    add_image_size( 'category-thumb', 200, 142 );
}
```

How do i stop the title tag from being added?

Comment: Why do you want to get rid of it?

Comment: @kaiser because i only want the src, alt, height, and width

Comment: That's exactly **no explanation**. I was asking for a reason and you're telling me your task...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This filter will remove it completely from all images, you can add a conditional to only effect certain images.

```
function remove_img_title($atts) {
    unset($atts['title']);
    return $atts;
}
add_filter('wp_get_attachment_image_attributes','remove_img_title');
```

---

Instead if you want to use `<?php the_post_thumbnail( 'category-thumb' ); ?>`

You can pass it an empty title using the second  `$attr` so your title tag will look like `title=" "`.

It would be:

```
$default_attr = array('title'   =>  ' ');
the_post_thumbnail('post-thumbnails', $default_attr);
```